# TextView Linkfy.AddLinks intercepts touch to the parent view in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, touch, touch-event

I'm using a renderer to list links to a text, when I click it it opens the browser. I want that when I click the link it needs to open at the same when I click simple text touch must be recognized.

```
    public class LabelWithHyperlinksRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public LabelWithHyperlinksRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                
                Control.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
                Linkify.AddLinks(Control, MatchOptions.WebUrls);
               
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, using **TapGestureRecognizer** is enough. Try the following code:

In .xaml

```
<Label
    Text="Hello, World!"
    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
    FontSize="32"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>             
</Label>
```

In .cs file,

```
string url = "https://www.youtube.com/";

async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
{
    await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Add a tap gesture recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap).

Hope it works for you.

Also, i found a useful link: [A Xamarin Android TextView that supports Linkify and gestures](https://gist.github.com/pmachapman/a988348a93933ac359ebe0d6a5314467).

Comment: I i found a useful link [A Xamarin Android TextView that supports Linkify and gestures](https://gist.github.com/pmachapman/a988348a93933ac359ebe0d6a5314467).